# Android Emulator displays visual elements incorrectly but clicks respond as if they are in correct position?

Tags: android, android-emulator

On windows 10, After a fresh install of Android studio 2.3.3, running the android emulator with a freshly downloaded VM on Nougat, the emulator looks like this:

[image: How my emulator looks]

As you can see, the visual output doesn't take up the whole frame, however in order to click on different buttons you have to click on the area of the screen the SHOULD be displayed.

Has anyone come across this problem and know how to fix? I've tried reinstalling, I could reinstall again but thought there might be something else going on.

Comment: Just to double check, you recreated the AVD (i.e. not just run from one built months ago) after you downloaded the latest version of the emulator image/SDK - correct?

Comment: yeah, it's a new image and fresh avd